# how to write this querySet with Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I started learning Django QuerySets but I didn't succeed to write it in this case where I must agregate 2 models related by a foreign key .

I have 2 models `user` and `course` where course contains a foreign key of `user`

```
class user(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

class Course(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(User)
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and I want to translate this `sql` statement into `querysets` :

```
select * from user u, course c 
where u.id = c.user_id
and c.course_name='science' ;
```

could someone help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is a set of courses with each course instance having a set of related users you do this:

```
Course.objects.select_related('user').filter(course_name='science')
```

Please see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

> select_related(*fields)   Returns a QuerySet that will “follow”
>   foreign-key relationships, selecting additional related-object data
>   when it executes its query. This is a performance booster which
>   results in a single more complex query but means later use of
>   foreign-key relationships won’t require database queries.

If on the other hand you want a list of users and the courses they are following you do

```
user.objects.filter(course__name='science')
```

This is the reverse traversal of a foreign key relationship. Please note that by convention django model names begin with an upper case latter. Your model is 'user' but really ought to be 'User'

Comment: Thanks for your quick response .. this returns a list of courses or users ?